# Phonegap bb app displays error after compiling

Tags: html

hello please iv got a problem,   i get this error when theres no active network when using my app i created, its a blackberry app

> you are currently in an area that cant handle data communication, as
>   a result the following resource could not retrived - http://
>   mydomain.com -   please try again when you are in a different
>   location, or contact your service provider if the problem persists.

it still occurs when i make use of the network connection pluging   is there any way i can sought this problem out, cuz it reveals the source of my app which isnt too good for my app thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the app's manifest to not require a persistent connection to http://mydomain.com? It sounds like you have not set the app permissions well ... or at all? Look here: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Without posting your config.xml, I cannot really help you. BUT, if you look here, too for specific BB info: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/code_sample_creating_a_bb_widget_config_document_834683_11.html

I see that the access request uri node has a require attribute. Does yours have this? Where is mydomain.com in your config.xml? Tht's where I'd be looking.

Comment: pls explain in details, let me post my config file thanks @cliffbarnes

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.whitechapelandpartners.my"
  versionCode="134.0"
        version   = "1.0">
    <name>my</name>

    <description>
 my
    </description>
<access origin="*" />
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="wolexx007@gmail.com">
   my
    </author><feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />

Comment: <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
   <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="50000" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />

    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
   
   

   
</widget>

Comment: is it the access origin ure talking off

Comment: Hi just now seeing this. Give me a bit to expand my answer...been busy with paying app development :)